Haproxy - how to setup basic auth with cookie based session
Using haproxy I'm trying to secure website using basic auth+session cookie:

user hitting page for the first time is asked for credentials
if valid - session is created and cookie is returned
following requests providing cookie referring to valid session are passed without the need to authenticate

So far I only managed to run it without actual session binding - I just check the presence of cookie.
frontend default
    acl auth_ok http_auth(AuthUsers)
    acl has_cookie hdr_sub(cookie) X-ProxyCookie
    http-request auth if !has_cookie
    http-request set-var(txn.hascookie) str(true) if has_cookie
    use_backend my_backend


backend my_backend
    acl cookie_found var(txn.hascookie) -i -m beg true
    http-response set-header Set-Cookie X-ProxyCookie=session-valid;path=/ if !cookie_found
    http-request del-header authorization
    server my_server 192.168.93.62:445 ssl verify none

Now I'd like to replace it with cookie X-ProxyCookie insert ..., but depending how do I try to approach it, i miss:

is a way to def define ACL to check if session cookie refers to valid session?
how to allow new session binding (the insert in the cookie directive) only if authorized with basic_auth?

Thanks for any ideas how to approach it...
m.
